# Filter pivot table conditionally

Tags: excel-2010, pivot-table

I need to make a pivot table of sales by cities. How can I filter it such that for Toronto and Montreal it will show sales > 50K and for other cities sales > 25K?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to adjust your source data to include a new column for "filtered" values. That column will have a formula to include your criteria. For example:

```
=if([city name]="Toronto",if([value]>50000,[value],if([value]>25000,[value],0)),0)
```

Then in the pivot table you use the new 'filtered value' column and filter out anything that is 0.

Comment: That's what I needed. Than you.